# Show parameters in Canopy?

Tags: canopy

I have to use Canopy for some schoolwork, but it doesn't seem to show parameters of functions I call. So, when I type `cv2.HoughCircle(` I would expect it to tell me what the first parameter should be. Is there a way to enable this in Canopy? Perhaps some plugin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you expect :

[image: method information]

You will have to press `Tab` for the autocomplete to show you information about the method. Can you try that? Also, is `cv2.HoughCircle` a well commented object, similar to `numpy.linspace` shown above?